# Python subprocess command is not getting executed

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

    try:
        command  = ['runas.exe','/user:Administrator','"bcdedit','/default','{78dj43af-9158-11e4-a25d-961c55rdf2df}"']
        print(str(command))
        prog = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        prog.communicate('123456')#Password for admin
        exitCode = prog.returncode
        print('Exit Code:-'+str(exitCode))

    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception is:' +str(e))
```

I could not figure out , what is the problem with current code.

Can somebody please tell me where I am committing mistake ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting Exit code as -1 also , the settings which is supposed to be changed (with bcdedit)is not happening. Is the code correct ?

Comment: Not the exit code, You say you have a problem, What is the problem, So when it catches in your except block then it will print out "Exception is: + str(e)". << What does this say in your case?

Comment: The code does not hit the exception part. I want to change some settings with the help of "bcdedit" with administrator rights, that change is not happening. This is the problem.

Comment: The quoting looks off.  I'm not familiar with the intricacies of Windows quoting, but I would expect the tail of the list to be either ...`'bcdedit','/default','{78dj43af-9158-11e4-a25d-961c55rdf2df}'`, without the broken double quotes, or a single string containing all these arguments.

Comment: I tried removing the double quotes also.. but that also did not work.        e.g.command  = ['runas.exe','/user:Administrator','bcdedit','/default','{78dj43af-9158-11e4-a25d-961c55rdf2df}']

Comment: I can execute the same command from command prompt : Like below             runas.exe /user:Administrator "bcdedit /default {78dj43af-9158-11e4-a25d-961c55rdf2df}"